# iOS 8.3 App Extension arm64 slice?

Tags: ios, arm64

could someone please help me understand the arm64 slice?

My app extension was working great until iOS 8.3 was released the other day. But now I have to go to "more"

[image]

in the activity controller to see my apps extension. If I turn off and on the UISwitch I will be able to use the extension.

[image]

However if I do the above statement, I will not see my app's extension. Currently my extension works great on iPhone 4s through iPhone 6 and iPads, it is just now not showing int the activity controllers options.

Here is apple's notes but I do not understand what they mean by 'slice'??

App Extensions
Notes

•   App extensions need an arm64 slice to run on 64-bit devices. If you try to run the armv7 slice on a 64-bit device it won’t work.

•   Apps need to have an arm64 slice if the bundle contains a framework that both the app and the app extension link against.

Thanks again if anyone can help me?

Comment: "but I do not understand what they mean by 'slice'" They mean the part of the compiled binary that is created for 64-bit architecture, as opposed to the part created for 32-bit architecture. If you build using normal architecture build settings, you get both, automatically. I don't see what you think this has to do with your actual problem, though.

Comment: I recommend that you watch the Architecting Modern iOS Games talk on this page: https://developer.apple.com/tech-talks/videos/ Despite the name, it is actually about 64-bitness, and explains all about slices.

Comment: Thank you matt I will do that now. I only think that it has something to do with my problem because Apple only had 2 "Extension Notes for 8.3"  talking about arm64. I don't really know whats going on tell you the truth.

Comment: My extension was working fine until 8.3. And it still works, only I have to go to more in the activities option and flip the UISwitch off and on, to get the extension Icon to show.

Comment: But that sounds like a system change reflected in how iOS 8.3 does things, not anything to do with your extension in particular.

Comment: Okay, I fixed by just creating one from scratch, yea it took about 5 mins but i still don't know what if different about the new extension compared to the older one. The info plist file is the same all the code is the same. I don't know? I cannot stand the mystery game but sometimes you just gotta quit searching for the issue even though you lose sleep over it. haha. Thanks again Matt for your help I knew in the back of my head it couldn't be the arm64 because I was using the standard arcs. Sooo... Guess my advice to the next developer in a weird issue like this I would try to make a new ext.

Comment: About the comment above in short, i didn't really fix it I just created a new one and now it works fine...

Comment: If there's no issue here, it would be good if you were to delete the question.